# Scale and move a layer simultaneously

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, calayer

I am using `CABasicAnimation` to change the bounds property and then using it to change the position property of a layer. Is it possibly to do both simultaneously? Kinda of like changing the frame of the `UIView`?

```
CGRect oldBounds = mask.bounds;
CGRect newBounds = CGRectMake(0,0, rect.size.width * scale, rect.size.height * scale);
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(newBounds));
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds"];

animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:oldBounds];
animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:newBounds];

mask.bounds = newBounds;
[mask addAnimation:animation forKey:@"bounds"];



CGPoint oldPos = mask.position;
CGPoint newPos = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x * scale, rect.origin.y * scale);

CABasicAnimation *animation2 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];

animation2.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:oldPos];
animation2.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:newPos];

mask.position = newPos;
[mask addAnimation:animation2 forKey:@"position"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Changed to give more correct animations...

You can add 2 animations at once...

Like this:

```
CALayer * myLayer ;

{
    CABasicAnimation * anim = [ CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position" ] ;
    anim.fromValue = [ NSValue valueWithCGPoint:layer.position ] ;
    [ layer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil ] ;
}

layer.position = <#newPosition#> ;

{
    CABasicAnimation * anim = [ CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds" ] ;
    anim.fromValue = [ NSValue valueWithCGRect:layer.bounds ] ;
    [ layer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil ] ;
}

layer.bounds = <#newBounds#> ;
```

Comment: Please check my code. Do you mean like that? With this way, it seems like it scales first,then moves.

Comment: seems like you answered your own question?

Comment: what happens if you remove the assignements to `layer.bounds` and `layer.position`? Also, with `addAnimation:forKey:`, the `key` argument is for your own reference--the layer doesn't care about it.

Comment: I updated my answer--I tried this code it should animate correctly. Note the use of `fromValue` and also assigning your toValues directly on the layers you are animating....